# F# making ToString method for a binary search tree

Tags: f#, binary-tree

I am currently building my binary tree in F#, and I'm almost finished. I'm on the last assignment of this task, where I am supposed to make a string representation of the binary tree. Meaning that the tree should be presented like this:

Example: `("node" "value" ("node" "value" "Empty" "Empty") Empty)` <- A tree with a rootnode that has a left subtree with a node that has two empty subtrees, and an empty right subtree.

My tree looks like this:

```
 type Btree<'a when 'a: comparison> = 
 |Node of  'a * Btree<'a> *Btree<'a> 
 |Leaf of 'a 
 |EmptyTree
```

This is how far I've gotten:

```
let rec treeToString bintree = 
    match bintree with
    |EmptyTree -> "Empty" //Check if the tree is empty
    |Node(inner, left, right) when inner = 0 -> "Empty"
    |Leaf x-> "Node"+x.ToString() //Returns "Node" and its value
    |Node(inner, left, right) when inner <> 0-> treeToString left //Need some kind of output here, but what?
    |Node(inner, left, right) when inner <> 0->treeToString right
```

My method only returns one value, so the actual problem with my solution is getting the recursive part right.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The union case `Leaf of 'a` is redundant because `Leaf(a)` can be modelled by `Node(a, Empty, Empty)`. Type declaration could be simplified to:

```
type BinTree<'a when 'a: comparison> = 
    | Empty 
    | Node of 'a * BinTree<'a> * BinTree<'a>
```

From the output sample `("node" "value" ("node" "value" "Empty" "Empty") Empty)`, you should display values of node elements first, then display left branches and right branches recursively:

```
let rec treeToString bintree = 
    match bintree with
    | Empty -> "Empty"
    | Node(value, left, right) -> 
      sprintf "(Node %O %s %s)" value (treeToString left) (treeToString right)
```

You can push this further by overriding `ToString()` method

```
type BinTree<'a> with
override x.ToString() = treeToString x
```

so that the type works with `sprintf "%O" bintree` and the like.

Comment: Guess I'll have to redesign my whole assignment before trying this! I'll get back as soon as I've done it

Comment: The change is easy because it only simplifies your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a function with `rec` only allows the function to call itself -- it doesn't actually implement the traversal strategy (in your case, the traversal of your binary tree).

You need to implement an [inorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Inorder) of the tree, like so:

```
let rec treeToString bintree = 
    match bintree with
    | EmptyTree -> "Empty" //Check if the tree is empty
    | Leaf x -> "Node" + x.ToString() //Returns "Node" and its value
    | Node(inner, left, right) when inner = 0 -> "Empty"
    | Node(inner, left, right) when inner <> 0 ->
        // Traverse the tree recursively
        treeToString left
        treeToString inner
        treeToString right
```

Comment: Due to my bad implementation of a bintree, this dosn't work, this method will only return a Leaf:(. Thank you for taking your time anyways!

Comment: You would need to combine the results of each recursive call in the last case, see pad's answer.